# Are dragons real animals?

Tags: zoology

I'm having this debate with someone on whether or not dragons are real. They say they are real because there's been thousands of historical sightings of them, and there was at least one historical case where a teenager said that a dragon had appeared and killed his friends, one by one, but he got away. For the rest of his life, this person was obsessed with dragons to the point of wanting to obtain the personal information and telephone numbers of anyone who claimed to have seen dragons.

So, now I am kind of conflicted, I responded to that person saying those people saying they've seen them are lying, and Wikipedia says that dragons are fictional, but they directed me to a paranormal forum saying that Wikipedia is unreliable, and also it's up to me to prove that the people who've seen dragons are just lying.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be appropriate on [Skeptics.SE], but please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/), instead request migration after consulting that sites help. ———— In addition, we expect you to demonstrate prior research with references to **reliable** sources — e.g. peer-reviewed research (definitely not paranormal forums) . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Dragons are real animals, but that almost certainly doesn't mean what you think it means**

'Dragons' are a diverse group of reptiles mostly within the Family Agamidae, comprising over [300 species throughout Africa, Asia, Australia and southern Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agamidae). As an example, here's an Eastern Bearded Dragon, which is relatively common throughout Southern and Eastern Australia. The largest male Eastern Bearded Dragons grow to around 60cm total length, and a personal friend of mine once kept one as a pet.

[image: image shared under cc-by-2.0; Donald Hobern]

The largest *real* 'dragon' is the [Komodo Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon) in the family Varanidae. These grow to a maximum length of around three meters and a maximum weight around 90 kilograms. They are top predators in the ecosystems where they live, and adults will take large mammals as prey. Here's a Komodo Dragon stalking a deer. You'll notice that it's wearing a GPS collar - it was being tracked by scientists trying to record their foraging behaviour. You can read their full paper in [PLoS ONE](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0011097).

[image: Bull JJ, Jessop TS, Whiteley M (2010) Deathly Drool: Evolutionary and Ecological Basis of Septic Bacteria in Komodo Dragon Mouths. PLoS ONE 5(6): e11097. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0011097]

However, it seems like you are mostly asking about [mythological dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon). Mythological dragons aren't real.